# Accessing Restangularized Data

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular in my Angular app.  I can successfully pull data from by backend.  However, I am having difficulty getting it to update the data after submitting a form.  The PUT method will work and will send the request to the API but the payload isn't correct.  It is sending the original data.  I can't seem to get the restangularized data to show up on my page.

I can make the response for my data available in the views by doing:

```
$scope.user = Restangular.one('user', 1234).get().$object;
```

The user information does not show up unless I put in `$object`.

If I just use:

```
$scope.user = Restangular.one('user', 1234).get();
```

My views don't display the user information, putting `{{user}}` will be `{"restangularCollection":false,"reqParams":null,"parentResource":null}`.

As I understand it, Restangular appends the different functions in order to enable the restful actions which is why `Restangular.one('user', 1234).get().$object` wouldn't be preferable.

I tried putting in setResponseExtractor() into my config per the documentation (https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-access-the-unrestangularized-element-as-well-as-the-restangularized-one) but it is overwritten by setResponseInterceptor() which I need to transform the response from getList() into an array.

Here is my controller:

```
props.controller('UserEditController', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Restangular) {
  var UserEdit = Restangular.one('users', $routeParams.userId).get();
  $scope.user_edit = Restangular.copy(UserEdit);
  console.log($scope.user_edit);
  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.project.put().then(function() {
    $location.path('/');
  });
});
```

My form:

```
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>
<form ng-submit="save_user()">
  <label for="first_name">First Name:
  <input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="user_edit.first_name" ng-value="user_edit.first_name" /><br />
  <label for="last_name">Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="last_name" ng-model="user_edit.last_name" ng-value="user_edit.last_name"/><br />
  <label for="email">Email:
  <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user_edit.email" ng-value="user_edit.email"/><br />
  <label for="position">Position:
  <input type="text" name="position" ng-model="user_edit.position" ng-value="user_edit.position"/><br />
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
  <a href="#/users/{{user_edit.id}}">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

I've looked over the Restangular example on Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka) and it got me aways but I can't seem to figure this out.  It is driving me crazy.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This only addresses the .$object portion of the question.

Restangular does everything with promises. Before the response data can be accessed, the promise has to be fulfilled/resolved.

```
// Assign data to $scope once response is returned.
Restangular.one('users', $routeParams.userId).get().then(function(user){
    $scope.user_edit = user;
});
```

Then putting {{user_edit}} in your view should display the user data.

Comment: what if the '$scope.user_edit' is accessed outside the function, then it becomes undefined [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114111/cant-access-a-scope-variable-outside-restangular-request)  @inskib