# Cant access a scope variable outside restangular request

Tags: angularjs, restangular

The rest api returns a json object on restangular get request and the response is only accessible inside the function

```
 Restangular.all('getUsers').getList().then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response;
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value, key) {    //This works
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });
  });

  angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value, key) {    //This does not work
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });
```

Comment: `getList()` is async. The `forEach()` outside of the callback runs before `getList()` returns and populates `$scope.users`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read (more) about promises in angularjs.

The function inside the then() is executed only after the REST request has returned a response.

The code below that is run immediately after the request has been send, but definitely before the response has been processed.

You could do

```
$scope.$watch("users", function() {
   angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value, key) {    //This does now work
           console.log(key + ': ' + value);
       });
});
```